# ¿Como puedo arreglar el despliegue de una aplicacion java (javafx)?

Tags: java

Mi problema esta en que quiero desplegar mi aplicacion haciendo doble click en el archivo jar de mi proyecto, pero no me deja al darle doble click en el archivo me muestra durante milisegundos una pantalla en negro con la ruta donde tengo javafx, mi proyecto es creado en netbeans de tipo ant, la cuestion es al introducir este comando "java --module-path "C:\ruta\completa\hacia\javafx-libs" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar "C:\ruta\completa\hacia\TuArchivo.jar" por el simbolo de sistema si me deja desplegarlo sin problemas, quiero saber como lo podria solucionar o donde esta el error.

Comment: Hola Santi, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el sistema operativo?